# How to disable Gatekeeper alerts on opening text files synced with Dropbox?

Tags: macos, text, dropbox, gatekeeper

I use WriteRoom to create and edit text files on the Mac (10.8.2). I keep these files in my DropBox (v1.6.14) folder so that they're synced to the cloud and can be edited on my iOS devices and other computers.

I had Gatekeeper set to allow applications downloaded from the App Store and identified developers:

[image]

And when I tried to open text files in my DropBox folder with WriteRoom, I got this Gatekeeper alert (which doesn't seem appropriate for the type of file it is):[image]

I found this annoying, so I set Gatekeeper to allow apps from 'anywhere'. But then I get this message on trying to open these files:[image]

I don't really mind how Gatekeeper is set but I would really like to disable these annoying warning messages. Does anyone know why they keep appearing and how they can be stopped?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man spctl`

That is good to know, although you can just do:

`xattr -d YourFile.txt`

This removes the quarantine attribute on files.

With spctl you can add WriteRoom to list of apps that can run. From

`man spctl`

```
EXAMPLES
 To check whether Mail.app is allowed to run on the local system:
       spctl -a /Applications/Mail.app

 To allow Frobozz.app to run on the local system:
       spctl --add --label "My Stuff" /Applications/Mail.app

 To forbid all code obtained from the Mac App Store from running:
       spctl --disable --label "Mac App Store"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've discovered that, with Gatekeeper set to allow apps 'from anywhere', previously opened files are remembered and allowed to open without displaying a warning message.

Comment: You probably don't want to do that. Perhaps add a folder action to Dropbox? Strip off the quarantine attribute on anything going in there, while still requiring strange apps to verify with you that they are going to run.